# Trouble Compiling Ubuntu Kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, ssl

I'm trying to compile a linux kernel for my Operating Systems class and keep getting this error can anyone help?

```
sudo make modules_install
```

```
  INSTALL arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko
cp: cannot stat 'arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko': No such file or directory
At main.c:291:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: /lib/modules/4.19.98/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko: No such file or directory
scripts/Makefile.modinst:36: recipe for target 'arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko] Error 1
Makefile:1256: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
```

Comment: Currently using linux-4.15.0-118-generic upgrading to linux-4.19.98

Comment: in my opinion there are other errors above. Also as I know when many years ago I have compiled the kernel, the command line is "make modules && make modules_install". From your error one modules was not been compiled then you can't install it.

Comment: OS & release:  Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: any luck with this ? I see the same error ...